# circuit design options between switching Servo GND vs switching vcc

Tags: arduino, servo

I have couple of design choices wondering which one is more appropriate, I am controlling a SG90 hobby servo with an Atmega328p using a NMOS. I could either switch the servo GND or servo VCC just wondering which is better, your suggestions will be welcome.

Switching servo diode

[image]

Secondly is it advisable to use  a flyback diode  ?

Comment: Its a bad idea to switch gnd - you get a sneak path back through the servo_ctrl wire that will cause you problems. Better to switch VCC using a pchan mosfet or other suitable device.

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing: why do you need to switch the servo power? the control pin usually is enough (some servo simply shutdown when there are no pulses; it's not guaranteed). Also you'll lose position keeping which somewhat negates the advantage of using a servo.

Anyway. Kartman is right, you'll risk to try to power up the servo thru the control line, unless you are really careful and put it in 3-state. I agree that a better solution would be to use a P-channel or some kind of load switch (if your servo is logic powered, as it seems, a P-channel is extremely easy to use).

As for the flyback diode, most probably it's already integrated as a part of the servo bridge. It doesn't hurt to be safe however.

I suspect the control pin *could* send back some bad transient on power on/off of the servo (just paranoid); check with a scope and in case protect the GPIO with a zener or something similar.

Comment: I need the switch to save power, its battery powered application where I need to put entire circuit to deep sleep, without FET I measured circuit is leaking 5mA all the time, even when servo is not active. Servo only comes on 3 or 4 times during entire day.